# Jquery validate dynamic drop downs with text box for default values

Tags: jquery

I have a button, which on click gives drop down + text box.

I need to validate the drop down if default value is selected.

ie) If i click the button when the drop down has default value, i should not be able to add drop downs.

**Design:**

Here the 2nd drop down has default value, still i am able to add another dd.

[image]

The code is working for only 1st dd.

```
<div class="fields_action"><br>
  <select id="action" class="increment" onchange="validateOnSelect(this)" style="position: relative;bottom: 32px;">
    <option value="N">Select Action</option>
    <option value="Y">SMS</option>
    <option value="Y">Call</option>
    <option value="Y">Call Back</option>
    <option value="Y">Email</option>
    <option value="Y">Website </option>
  </select>
  <input name="default_text" id="default_text_id" value="" type="text" style="position: relative;bottom: 32px;"><br/>
  <span style="color:red;" class="key-error-class"  id="key_error_1" ></span>
  <span id="valueResponse_1" class="valueResponse-class"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("default_text_id").disabled = true;
  var add_button = $("#btnAdd"); //Add button ID
  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    var actionid = $('#action');
    if ($("#action")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
      alert("Please select");
    }
    if (actionid.val() === '' || actionid.val() === 'N') {
      alert("Please select an item from the list and then proceed!");
      $('#action').focus();
      return false;
    }
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div><select id="action" class="increment" required><option value="N">Select Action</option><option value="Y">Call</option><option value="Y">Call Back</option><option value="Y">Email</option><option value="Y">Website </option></select> &nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="TextAdPriority" class="" value="" type="text"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><br/><br/></div>');
        if ($("#action")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
            alert("Please select");
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: unrelated but why `$(add_button)` when add_button is already a jquery object?  Also I saw in a previous question, you used a delegated bind for your remove button, so why not just do that for your change event? instead of using inline?  Otherwise just add the inline to your select you create when you append it to the wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code like this to validate dropdowns. It is correctly working for me.

Updated code for input validation.

- Modified options value in html.
- Added validate_input function to validate input based on different dropdown values.

  HTML

  ```
   <div class="fields_action"><br>
    <div class="fields">
      <select id="action" class="increment" style="position: relative;bottom: 32px;">
          <option value="N">Select Action</option>
          <option value="sms">SMS</option>
          <option value="call">Call</option>
          <option value="callback">Call Back</option>
          <option value="email">Email</option>
          <option value="website">Website </option>
       </select><br/>
         <input name="default_text" id="default_text_id" value="" type="text" style="position: relative;bottom: 32px;"><br/>
    </div>
  </div
  ```

  Js

  ```
   $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
   //alert('asas');
    e.preventDefault();

    var fields = $('.fields');
    var isValid = true

    fields.map(function(idx, field) {
     var select = $(field).find('select');
     var input = $(field).find('input');
     if (select.val() === '' || select.val() === 'N' || input.val() === '') {
      alert(`Please fill all details on position ${idx+1} and then proceed!`);

      select.val() === '' || select.val() === 'N' ? select.focus() : input.focus();

      isValid = false;
     } else {
       isValid = validate_input(select.val(), input);
     }
   })

   if(isValid && x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
     x++; //text box increment
     $(wrapper).append('<div class="fields"><select id="action" class="increment" required><option value="N">Select Action</option><option value="Y">Call</option><option value="Y">Call Back</option><option value="Y">Email</option><option value="Y">Website </option></select> &nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="TextAdPriority" class="" value="" type="text"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><br/><br/></div>');
   }

  });

  function validate_input(selectVal, input) {
   switch(selectVal) {
    case 'sms':
     //your validation
    case 'call':
     //your validation
    case 'callback':
     //your validation
    case 'email':
     var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
     var valid = regex.test(input.val());
     if(!valid) 
      { 
       alert("invalid email")
       input.focus();
      }
      return valid;
    case 'website':
     //your validation
    default:
    return true;
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: What about textboxes for each drop down

Comment: Just one more question, i have drop down with email and mobile numbers (but there is only text box with same id for all dd values), how to validate them using jquery based on dd value selection, ie) if i select email, one validation should apply, if i select phone no, other validation should get applied

Comment: Just want to clarify, So can you select single dropdown value (email or mobile) at a time ? It would be good If you elaborate your requirement.

Comment: Same design as in question. For each drop down value (SMS/Email/Website ),  i have to validate its text field next to it..ie), if i select SMS in drop down, i want to validate its text field(for number only), if i select email from drop down, its corresponding text field, i want to validate for email..

Comment: I modified above code to work for input validation. I added email validation for testing. you can add more validation as per your need.